# How to unpack a summary table into separate records with SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a db table with summarized data, but I want to unpack it into a table of details.

**Summary Table:**

```
id  speed color  count
---------------------
1   50    red    2
2   50    blue   1
3   70    orange 2
```

**Detail Table (Desired):**

```
id speed color  count
---------------------
1   50   red    1
1   50   red    1
2   50   blue   1
3   70   orange 1
3   70   orange 1
```

Is this possible to do with a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
select id, speed, color, 1 as cnt
from summary t, lateral
     generate_series(1, t.count) g
```

Comment: seems to work without the `g`. is it actually required?

Comment: @tim_xyz . . . I like to provide table aliases.  In this case, it is not necessary.